# Filtering Lists of Tuples by Elements of Tuples

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7

I am working in Python (2.7.9) and am trying to filter a list of tuples by a list of elements of those tuples. In particular, my objects have the following form:

```
tuples = [('a', ['a1', 'a2']), ('b',['b1', 'b2']), ('c',['c1', 'c2'])]
filter = ['a', 'c']
```

I am new to Python and the easiest way to filter the tuples that I could discover was with the following list comprehension:

```
tuples_filtered = [(x,y) for (x,y) in tuples if x in filter]
```

The resulting filtered list looks like:

```
tuples_filtered = [('a', ['a1', 'a2']), ('c',['c1', 'c2'])]
```

Unfortunately, this list comprehension seems to be very inefficient. I suspect this is because my list of tuples is much larger than my filter, the list of strings. In particular, the filter list contains 30,000 words and the list of tuples contains about 134,000 2-tuples.

The first elements of the 2-tuples are largely distinct, but there are a few instances of duplicate first elements (not sure how many, actually, but by comparison to the cardinality of the list it's not many).

My question: **Is there a more efficient way to filter a list of tuples by a list of elements of those tuples?**

(Apologies if this is off-topic or a dupe.)

Related question (which does not mention efficiency):

[Filter a list of lists of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40496831/filter-a-list-of-lists-of-tuples)

Comment: So how large is your real `filter` list? Why do you feel this is inefficient, do you have profiling information for your real situation?

Comment: The filter list contains 30,000 words and the list of tuples contains about 134,000 2-tuples.

Comment: If list comprehension doesn't work for you, you should think of a module like `numpy` which has been implemented in C. But note that in that case you should have a large list, otherwise the cost of converting your python list to a `numpy` array would be more than the performance you gain from `numpy`.

Comment: @Silenus: there's your problem then, the `filter` list.

Comment: Is the `filter` sorted? Instead of using `in` you could use a binary search with `bisect`

Comment: Try turning your list of tuples into a dict and iterating over your filter getting the (key, values) pairs. I won't post this as an answer since I can't test its efficiency now but it may be worth a try.

Comment: @rbierman: that would only bring it down to O(logN); a set is unbeatable there.

Comment: @lucasnadalutti: that would only work if the first elements are unique. Order may matter too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In a comment you write:

> The filter list contains 30,000 words and the list of tuples contains about 134,000 2-tuples.

`in` containment tests against a list takes O(N) linear time, which is *slow* when you do this 134k times. Each time you have to iterate over all those elements to find a match.  Given that you are filtering, not all those first elements are going to be present in the 30k list, so you are executing up to 30k * 134k == 4 billion comparisons.

Use a *set* instead:

```
filter_set = set(filter)
```

Set containment tests are O(1) constant time; now you reduced your problem to 134k tests.

A much smaller component of time you can avoid spending is the tuple assignment; use indexing to extract just the one element you are testing with:

```
tuples_filtered = [tup for tup in tuples if tup[0] in filter_set]
```

Comment: As the size of the filter list is much less than the size of the 2-tuples list, how about converting the 2-tuples list into a dictionary (using zip perhaps) and iterating over the filter list instead.

I am not sure if this would be efficient. Will the list in the value field of the dictionary be a copy or a reference?
If it is will be a reference, then this approach should be more efficient.

Comment: Reduces the `O(n*m)` of OPs answer to `O(n)`

Comment: @agamagarwal No need for `zip` to turn it into a `dict`, doing `mydict = dict(tuples)` is enough.

Comment: @agamagarwal: that would require those first elements to be unique.

Comment: @lucasnadalutti Oh yeah! Thanks.

Anyway, I just checked. When converting the tuples list into a dictionary, the list (['a1', 'a2']) is assigned to the value as a reference. So the iterating over the filter list instead of the tuples should be faster than this answer's approach.

Comment: @Silenus Could you confirm whether the first elements of the tuples are distinct?

Comment: If the fist elements are unique and you use the `mydict = dict(tuples)` from a comment above, the comprehension could look like: `tuples_filtered = [(x,mydict[x]) for x in filter]`

Comment: @John: don't forget to test if `x` is actually present in the dictionary. This does change the order of the output, drastically so.

Comment: @agamagarwal, the first elements of the tuples are largely distinct, but there are a few instances of duplicate first elements (not sure how many, actually, but by comparison to the cardinality of the list it's not many).

Comment: I'd be hesitant to change the tuples, as that makes the implementation dependent on the data... this implementation `set(filter)` is not. I'd use this even if they were distinct, as future duplicate additions may invalidate the output in ways that would be very difficult to detect, as it silently ignores duplicates.