# Remove items out of a python tuple

Tags: python, tuples

I have a list of tuples with word frequencies and a list of words to eliminate. How to avoid loops and delete tuples from a list?

```py
data = [('the',23),('for',15),('so',10),('micro',10),('if',10),('macro',10)]
words = ['so','is','for','if'] # unique
indice =[]

# %%
for ii in range(len(data)):
    for jj in range(len(words)):
        if words[jj]==data[ii][0]:
            print(words[jj]+ ': found')
            indice.append(ii)

# del data[indice]      # doesn't work
# data.remove(indice)   # doesn't work
```

Comment: Try `for i in reversed(indice): del data[i]`

Comment: Make `words` a set then iterate over `data` once; use `in` .

Comment: *"How to delete words from tuple?"* It seems you don't want to delete anything **from** tuples (which is impossible), but want to delete tuples from a list.

Comment: Does [Filtering Lists of Tuples by Elements of Tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40639995/filtering-lists-of-tuples-by-elements-of-tuples) answer your question?

Comment: Why would you think you can "avoid loops", what do you mean by that exactly?

Comment: What is this "optimization problem" you speak of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would transform the word list to a set for faster lookups, and then use a list comprehension:

```py
wordset = set(wordset)
[item for item in data if item[0] not in wordset]
```

This outputs:

```py
[('the', 23), ('micro', 10), ('macro', 10)]
```

Answer (score -1):

This is precisely what the built-in *filter()* function is useful for.

No explicit loop here.

e.g.,

```
data = [('the',23),('for',15),('so',10),('micro',10),('if',10),('macro',10)]
words = ['so','is','for','if']

indice = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] not in words, data))

print(indice)
```

**Output:**

```
[('the', 23), ('micro', 10), ('macro', 10)]
```

As has been pointed out in an earlier comment, *words* should be a set for enhanced performance